# Fill missing height values with the known weight value

Tags: python, pandas

There is a data frame with Series of height and weight and some other data.
I'm using python, pandas
total there are 4673 records.
valid weight records: 4435
valid height records: 3242

Are there any good example to use use the existing weight and height to find to a function then fill the missing values?

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. Alas your question does not meed the requirements for a valid question: Please always provide an example that someone trying to help you can run. This is no place for general questions. Google for the pandas `fillna` function, maybe this will help you, then come back with the code you tried.

Comment: you can train a linear model on weight data to model height using the data you have, then use that model to predict for data where the height is missing\

Answer (score 0):

I think, you could use a Machine Learning Algorithm.

Do you know scikit learn ? https://scikit-learn.org/stable/
I recommend this algorithm : https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html

Knowing the height or the weight, you could predict the missing Value !

---

OR
You could use some statistical knowledge, like the Gaussian one. https://fr.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fichier:Gaussian_Filter.svg

Answer (score 0):

This is labelled as a pandas question, but is actually a question about imputation.

There are many, many imputation techniques, but regression is a good approach here.

First we need some data to play with. Purely random data won't be useful, we need something that makes sense, but has *some* randomness.

Note, per google, the avg. Male height is 175.4 cm; I'll use a standard deviation of 10 cm for height (I'm making up that number).

I'll use BMI to calculate a height. BMI formula is kg/(m*m). I'm going to use a mean of 28.6 (the average american adult male BMI, a value on which I'll reserve comment). Arbitrarily I'm using 5 as my BMI standard deviation.

Note: taking a random sample of height and then calculating weight from it was arbitrary (making up heights and calculating weights from it would have been equally valid), but if we want sample data that will be useful for regression we need there to be a pattern, we can't just make a random sample of both.

```py
#kg = bmi*m*m
df = pd.DataFrame({'height_cm': np.random.normal(175.4,10,50),
                   'bmi': np.random.normal(28.6,5,50)}
                 )
df['weight_kg'] = df['bmi']*(df['height_cm']/100)*(df['height_cm']/100)
```

Now we'll use linear regression on this data to make a formula to calculate height from weight (or weight from height)

```py
# We only want data with height and weight for regression
#    Make a mask so we can easily accesss these records
mask = (df.height_cm.notnull()) & (df.weight_kg.notnull())
mask_ht = (df.height_cm.notnull())
mask_wt = (df.weight_kg.notnull())

# transform your data so sklearn is happy
X = df.loc[mask,'height_cm'].values.reshape(-1,1)
y = df.loc[mask,'weight_kg'].values.reshape(-1,1)
# make and train a linear regression model
lr = LinearRegression()
lr.fit(X=X,y=y)
# use the model to make predictions
# apply it to the part of the where we only have height
#    making this a separate column so it's clear what's going onlr = LinearRegression()
#    note: using bitwise XOR
X_pred = df.loc[mask ^ mask_ht,'height_cm'].values.reshape(-1,1)
df.loc[mask ^ mask_ht,'weight_kg_pred'] = lr.predict(X_pred)
# we could rearrange the intercept and coef to calculate the height
#    from the existing lr object, but it's less work to make a new one

# Make a new lr to pred height based on wt
# using weight as independent variable here
lr_inv = LinearRegression()
lr_inv.fit(X=y,y=X)
y_pred = df.loc[mask ^ mask_wt,'weight_kg'].values.reshape(-1,1)
df.loc[mask ^ mask_wt,'height_cm_pred'] = lr_inv.predict(y_pred)
```

output (note: I didn't do anything for records missing height and weight, try mean value imputation there)

```
,height_cm,bmi,weight_kg,weight_kg_pred,height_cm_pred
0,154.47440488054778,21.840523800122202,52.116604320580656,,
1,176.09627542839243,39.52950013740323,122.58057759385566,,
2,186.40152269332447,32.33928935044303,,98.47669386777481,
3,179.9259604426291,35.998303452978405,116.53857217706638,,
4,173.0016516787748,17.763355383512597,,85.91296604132962,
5,185.85266024456368,32.636455945254006,112.73027215402762,,
6,174.3967733442522,32.8205318342341,99.82113533568734,,
7,170.0997326114241,24.47104880313847,,83.19212482599413,
8,,32.87513921325899,99.18063095394797,,177.13255317243465
9,,25.29035630571537,76.26139611992079,,171.59087747577607
```